# Safari forgets plug-in settings

Tags: macos, safari, plugins

I have configured Safari (8.0.7, Yosemite 10.10.4) to prompt me to allow Flash on a site by site basis. Most websites I block and some I set to "allow always" However, every couple of days, all the blocked/allowed sites are lost and I am prompted again (note that I have not reset any part of Safari during these times).

How can I fix this please?